# generate Java classes from XSD ant

Tags: java, ant, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have multiple xsd's file and all are starting with the root element as "response".

When I tried to generate Java classes from the below configuration

```
 <xjc destdir="${ext.tourcms.path}/gensrc" >
    <schema dir="${ext.tourcms.path}/resources/xsd/" includes="*.xsd"/>
    <produces dir="${ext.tourcms.path}/gensrc/com/jaxb">
     <include name="*.java" />
    </produces>
   </xjc>
```

[ERROR] 'response' is already defined

How can generate Java classes even though xsd's contains same root element.

Thanks,
Sree.

Comment: Is it exactly the same root element or is just the name the same?

Comment: Only the name of the root element is same